# proving a given quadratic equation does not have rational roots

Tags: linear-algebra, roots, quadratics, factoring

given a,b,c are rational , prove that $(a+b-c)x^2 +(a+c-b)x+(b+c-a)=0$
 does not have rational roots. i tried finding discriminant which simplified to $-3b^2+5c^2+5a^2-6ac-2bc-2ba$.now how to prove that it is not a perfect square of a rational number?

Comment: $a=b=1, c=0$ gives a counter-example to your statement.

Comment: When $a+b+c = 0$, one have a rational root $x = 1$.

Comment: @user69608 are you sure you don't have $a,b,c>0$ omited? Let $a,b,c$ be rational and $d$ be their common denominator, i.e. $d=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c)$ then $p=ad,\,q=bd,\,r=cd$ will be integers and you have to show that $d\left((a+b−c)x^2+(a+c−b)x+(b+c−a)\right)=0$ can't have rational roots. Maybe [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) could be useful

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin yes a,b,c are given rational only

Comment: @Alexey, $a=b=1$, $c=2$ shows rational roots even when $a,b,c>0$.

Comment: It's obvious, 69608, that the question, as stated, is nonsense. Somebody goofed somewhere.

Comment: @GerryMyerson i also think so. equation may have rational or irrational roots both.

Comment: Even there are more interesting examples, e.g. $54x^2+111x+35=0$ for $a = \frac{165}{2}, b = \frac{89}{2}, c = 73$ @GerryMyerson